# Unit tangent vector understanding

Tags: vectors, arc-length, tangent-line

[image]

So I have this question here. I did part a) . That was not too bad and I got it correct.

I'm not really sure what part (b) is asking though. I know how to calculate the unit tangent vector using:

[image]

but I'm not really sure how to incorporate the arc length parameter into this. What does that mean exactly? It's been almost 4 years since I did Calculus II haha xD .

Answer (score 1):

The calculation of the unit tangent vector can be found by using the 
[formula](http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/202/vectorFunctions/tannorm.htm)

```
                                    v(t) 
           T(t)  =                       
                           ||v(t)||
```

That is to say that the vector is divided by its norm to arrive at the unit vector. An example is given in the link.

The calculation of the derivative of unit tangent vector T, with respect to the arc length, ds, can be found by using the so=called [Frenet formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas). dT/ds = k N, where N is the unit normal vector, and k is the so-called curvature.

Comment: I got that but what does it mean by "with respect to the arc length parameter" ?

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty: The other equations you might want to consult are the Frenet formulas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas, where dT/ds is "with respect to the arc length parameter."

Comment: I see it but I am not really seeing hot they help :S . I'm sorry >.< .

Comment: Do I just use the formula as normal and just reparametrize everything in terms of the arc length?

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty: That's my understanding.

Comment: Thanks. I get it. I just wish there was a way to verify this >.< .